# ComponentDidMount getting triggered before redirect callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, oauth, azure-ad-msal

I'm using React framework.
When I login using `loginRedirect()` method, I get redirected back to the redirect uri I had provided - `https:localhost:3000`.

After the redirect (back into my page) when `componentDidMount()` is called, `msalInstance.getAccount()` returns null as token hasn't been created yet.
After this the redirect callback is triggered.

`componentDidMount()` gets called before Trigger of redirect callback and token creation.
Hence I have to reload the page after the redirection so that `msalInstance.getAccount()` present inside `componentDidMount()` works.
How can I handle this situation?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with v2.0.0-beta of @azure/msal-browser.
It was subsequently fixed in the next release-v2.0.0-beta.1

Answer (score 0):

Your getting null because you are not waiting for your response. Try using Promises or async/await in componentDidMount()

Comment: I'm using async/await, the token is created after page load.
The token is not present at the time the redirect occurs, hence `const account = msalInstance.getAccount()` returns `null`

Comment: Your not waiting for your response. Try

const account = await msalInstance.getAccount()

Comment: It doesn’t return a promise.